# PHP - Add every x characters opening and closing tag in array

Tags: php

I'm getting a really long text (string )from database row which contains a lot of html tags including images, links etc. mixed up.

I would like to wrap every lets say 20 sentences to div. Also would like to wrap every image to div, no matter the position of image in string.

Is it possible? Any ideas how to achive this?

Thanks for every help.

This is a example from database, simple `echo $row['text_field']`

```
    <p><a href="https://www.ov-a.cz/cs/">Ateliér ov-a (Opočenský Valouch architekti)</a>&nbsp;si za svoju pomerne krátku dobu existencie získal oprávnenú pozornosť laickej a odbornej verejnosti. Ich návrhy sú charakteristické jasným konceptom a kvalitným spracovaním detailov. Zo všetkých ich prác môžeme vymenovať tie najvýraznejšie: komplex apartmánových hotelov Svatý Vavřinec v Peci pod Sněžkou, nové sídlo firmy Lasvit v Novém Boru alebo prepojovací mosty budov VŠCHT v Prahe.<br />
&nbsp;<br /></p>
<p><img alt="" src="image" /></p>
```

Example of string 2:

```
<p><a href="http://www.kuklica-smerek.com">Kuklica Smerek Architekti + Hubinský</a>&nbsp;je zoskupenie ateliérov Kuklica x Smerek architekti a Hubinsky atelier. Keďže sa tvorebne dopĺňajú a zdieľajú rovnaký priestor a názory, rozhodli sa pracovať spoločne na väčšine klientských zadaniach či súťažiach.</p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/TeamFotky_HubinskyKuklicaSmerek-5.jpg" /><p>

<p>Kuklica Smerek Architekti vznikol v roku 2015. Tvorba tohoto ateliéru je proces, v ktorom sa snažia čo najlepšie pochopiť svet okolo nás a vplyv architektúry na každodenný život. Od začiatku pracujú na rozmanitých projektoch a mierkach, čo ich núti uvažovať o každom zadaní zo všetkých uhlov. Pri návrhoch hľadajú logické a zároveň koncepčné riešenia, rešpektujú tradície aj genius loci, no zároveň veria aj v nabúravanie zaužívaných spoločenských stereotypov.</p>

<p>Hubinsky atelier je architektonické štúdio založené Jurajom Hubinským v roku 2015. Súčasnú architektonickú činnosť charakterizujú projekty viacerých mierok od interiérov, skrz budovy až po urbanizmus. Princíp tvorby spočíva v hľadaní možností, rozmýšľaní nad konceptom a kontextom, práci s úprimnou materialitou či zmyslom pre detail a vtip. Každé zadanie vníma ako akýsi prototyp, ktorý si zaslúži špecifickú pozornosť. Ďalšou témou, ktorej sa ateliér venuje sú výtvarné intervencie do architektonického priestoru. Okrem pracovných návykov pestujeme aj smiech, či rajčiny.</p>
```

Example of string 3:

```
<p><a href="https://www.ov-a.cz/cs/">Ateliér ov-a (Opočenský Valouch architekti)</a>&nbsp;si za svoju pomerne krátku dobu existencie získal oprávnenú pozornosť laickej a odbornej verejnosti. Ich návrhy sú charakteristické jasným konceptom a kvalitným spracovaním detailov. Zo všetkých ich prác môžeme vymenovať tie najvýraznejšie: komplex apartmánových hotelov Svatý Vavřinec v Peci pod Sněžkou, nové sídlo firmy Lasvit v Novém Boru alebo prepojovací mosty budov VŠCHT v Prahe.<br />
&nbsp;<br />
Pri kladení správnych otázok sa v architektonickom fachu stretávame pri riešenom projekte s objavovaním pragmatických a pravdivých, no zároveň unikátnych odpovedí. Jedným z dôležitých aspektov je teda práve dialóg a spoločné úsilie architekta a investora. Tohto pravidla sa držia naši susedia z Pražského ateliéru ov-a, ktorý založili v roku 2007 Jiří Opočenský a Štěpán Valouch. Popri vedení vlastnej kancelárie sa venujú zároveň výučbe na FA ČVUT, v praxi zase spoločne neprestajne prehlbujú svoje poznanie spoluprácou v stálom okruhu špecializovaných profesistov.</p>

<p style="text-align: center;"><a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/ova_jiri%20opocensky%20stepan%20valouch_02.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/ova_jiri%20opocensky%20stepan%20valouch_02.jpg" /></a></p>

<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><em>"Pro každý projekt hledáme jednotící koncept, který lze vyjádřit logem, a který nás vede v průběhu další práce až k realizaci stavby."</em></strong></p>

<p>Skice, vizualizácie v&nbsp;procese, fyzické modely širších aj detailných mierok, to všetko zahŕňa pedantný proces navrhovania OV-a v&nbsp;kombinácii s&nbsp;častým dialógom s&nbsp;klientom. Všetky úkony sledujú jeden spoločný cieľ: návrh by mal poskytnúť v&nbsp;rámci rozumných stavebných nákladov investora prínos trvalej hodnoty stavby. Vo svojom portfóliu OV-a dokazujú, že sa v&nbsp;Českej Republike s&nbsp;neustálym sledovaním požiadaviek a&nbsp;správnou, no progresívnou ambíciou dá produkovať zodpovedná súčasná architektúra.</p>

<hr />
<p>Jedným z&nbsp;príkladných počinov je&nbsp;<strong>rekonštrukcia uhoľne z&nbsp;30. rokov na neformálne aktivity pražskej školy VŠCHT</strong>. Uhoľňa postavená ako jednoduchá priemyselná stavba slúžila pre zásobovanie susedných kotolní až do roku 1985. Betónový objekt zložený z dvojice síl so šikmým dnom a&nbsp;cisternou v&nbsp;strednej veži pôsobil na prvý pohľad kvôli nedostatku rovných plôch ako ťažšie využiteľný priestor.&nbsp;</p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/Zm%C4%9Bna%20vyu%C5%BEit%C3%AD%20prostoru%20uhelny%20V%C5%A0CHT_01.jpg" /></p>

<p>Pohlaď do rezu s dvoma naklopenými plochami priviedol architektov na myšlienku využitia jednej strany na auditórium. Dominantná betónová konštrukcia bola ošetrená a&nbsp;zachovaná v&nbsp;celej svojej pôvodnej štruktúre.&nbsp;&nbsp;Jedným z&nbsp;hlavných cieľov bolo získať súvislý otvorený živý priestor slúžiaci prednáškam a&nbsp;neformálnym pracovným stretnutiam. Jedna z výsypiek bola preto odstránená a na druhej sa naopak vytvorilo hľadisko v&nbsp;mäkkom materiálovom prevedení vo forme drevených stupňov.&nbsp;&nbsp;Pre prepojenie oboch výškových úrovní sa zároveň vytvorilo nové oceľové schodisko.</p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/Zm%C4%9Bna%20vyu%C5%BEit%C3%AD%20prostoru%20uhelny%20V%C5%A0CHT_02.jpg" /></p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/Zm%C4%9Bna%20vyu%C5%BEit%C3%AD%20prostoru%20uhelny%20V%C5%A0CHT_04.jpg" /></p>

<p>Nové využitie uholne je vo svojej podstate jednoduchá odpoveď na komplexnú požiadavku investora. Z&nbsp;nenápadnej, no ťažkej priemyselnej stavby, uvoľnením objemu odstránením sýpky, zachovaním a zvýraznením dominantnej, logoidnej betónovej konštrukcie pridaním mäkkých-prírodných, funkčných solitérov sa majstrom OV-a podarilo vytvoriť ucelený čitateľný, fungujúci živý priestor.</p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/Zm%C4%9Bna%20vyu%C5%BEit%C3%AD%20prostoru%20uhelny%20V%C5%A0CHT_05.jpg" /></p>

<p>Jednou z&nbsp;najstarších no veľmi hodnotných realizácií je taktiež <strong>samostatný&nbsp;objekt záhradnej knižnice v&nbsp;Revniciach</strong>. Príbeh tejto stavby hovorí o&nbsp;akte ustúpenia potrebného nového objemu do úzadia starého rodinného domu. Hovorí o neparazitovaní novým objemom, o&nbsp;vytvorení cesty cez záhradu za denne využívaným priestorom.</p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/Zahradn%C3%AD%20knihovna%20%C5%98evnice_01.jpg" /></p>

<p>Dom z&nbsp;20. rokov,&nbsp;&nbsp;určený pôvodne ako letný domček, sa pre rodinu klienta stal celoročne obývaným objektom. Jednou zo zásadných potrieb klienta bolo vytvorenie pohodlného priestoru pre stovky kníh a&nbsp;s&nbsp;ním pokojný priestor pre štúdium. Aj napriek nedostatku priestoru v objekte, synergia architektonických hodnôt domu a romantickej&nbsp;letnej záhrady odmietla akúkoľvek dostavbu alebo prílepok k&nbsp;existujúcej stavbe.&nbsp;</p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/Zahradn%C3%AD%20knihovna%20%C5%98evnice_03.JPG" /></p>

<p>Štepán Valouch v&nbsp;spolupráci s&nbsp;Janom Marešom sa preto rozhodli navrhnúť dôstojného partnera k domu a záhrade. Miesto ubratia záhrady okolo domu knižnica obohacuje pobyt rodiny o zážitok z cesty cez divokú starú záhradu a cestu vertikálnym priestorom - oceľovým schodiskom okolo políc s knihami, až po vrchnú čitáreň s výhľadom na okolité, vegetáciou-podmanené prostredie. I&nbsp;v&nbsp;tomto prípade sa rukopis tvorby ateliéru prejavuje v&nbsp;dôslednej komunikácii s&nbsp;klientom. Stavebník prejavil veľkú dávku dôvery a veľkorysosti, bez ktorej by táto stavba nikdy nevznikla.</p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/Zahradn%C3%AD%20knihovna%20%C5%98evnice_02.JPG" /></p>

<p>Veľká časť práce OV-A má zásluhu na kvalitných a komplexných návrhoch v architektonických súťažiach. Jednou z&nbsp;nich je aj <strong>súťaž na&nbsp;rekonštrukciu a&nbsp;dostavbu sklárskej firmy LASVIT</strong>, ktorú po výhre 1. miesta ateliér úspešne zrealizoval na architektonicky čitateľné logo firmy a&nbsp;landmark mesta.</p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/S%C3%ADdlo%20firmy%20Lasvit_03.jpg" /></p>

<p>Zadaním klienta bolo vytvoriť sídlo firmy, ktoré nadväzuje na silnú sklársku tradíciu a&nbsp;spojuje sklo a&nbsp;svetlo súčasným jazykom. Ich artefakty sú umiestnené po celom svete a&nbsp;patria medzi špičku v&nbsp;odbore.</p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/S%C3%ADdlo%20firmy%20Lasvit_01.JPG" /></p>

<p>Domy na Palackého námestí v Novom Bore sú od konca 18. storočia obývané sklármi. Spoločnosť Lasvit sa rozhodla obnoviť obe historické pamiatky a je odhodlaná reprezentovať znovu oživenie autentickej sklárskej tradície Nového Boru. Tradičné historické objekty boli doplnené ďalšími dvoma podobne veľkými a tvarovanými abstraktnými čierno-bielymi objemami, čím sa vytvorila harmonická a funkčná zmes pôvodného historického kontextu a&nbsp;novej sviežej vrstvy.</p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/S%C3%ADdlo%20firmy%20Lasvit_02.jpg" /></p>

<p>Návrh interpretuje súčasnou formou typický dvojpodlažný sklársky dom a spojuje areál v&nbsp;harmonický celok. Sklenený dom je knižnicou vzoriek a&nbsp;priestorom pre jednanie, čierny dom je naopak skladom a&nbsp;showroomom k&nbsp;predstavení nových artefaktov 1:1.</p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/S%C3%ADdlo%20firmy%20Lasvit_12.JPG" /></p>

<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>"Návrh hovorí o vzťahu medzi dvoma domami, pôvodne barokovými chatami a ich modernou inkarnáciou."</strong></p>

<p>Domy svojím totožným objemom dosiahli jedinečný tvar ako z&nbsp;vonkajšej, tak aj z vnútornej strany - čierny dom je sám o sebe uzavretý, zatiaľ čo presklený dom je ako žiariaca lampa osvetľujúca mesto. Logom tohto objemu orientovaného do ulice je práve unikátna sklenená fasáda, reprezentujúca znak omladenia a progresu sklárstva a jeho dôvery v&nbsp;regióne.</p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/S%C3%ADdlo%20firmy%20Lasvit_07_BoysPlayNice.jpg" /></p>

<p>OV-a tak znova interpretujú silnú ambíciu a&nbsp;schopnosť kombinácie dobrej architektúry a správneho dialógu s&nbsp;klientom. Svojím rukopisným architektonickým pravidlom obohatili firmu o&nbsp;silnú koncepčnú no zároveň estetickú formu reprezentácie sklárskeho remesla.</p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/S%C3%ADdlo%20firmy%20Lasvit_05_BoysPlayNice.jpg" /></p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/S%C3%ADdlo%20firmy%20Lasvit_04_BoysPlayNice.jpg" /></p>

<p>Jedným z&nbsp;najväčších projektov ateliéru je&nbsp;<strong>Aparthotel v&nbsp;Peci pod Snežkou</strong>. Súčasná, udržateľná, horská architektúra ponúka viac než len ubytovanie. Štyri apartmánové domy na lúke, ktorá kryje obchodné parter a služby. Apartmánové domy vznikli na mieste pôvodnej predajne z 80. rokov. Štyri domy sú umiestnené na "lúke" - zelenej streche nad obchodným parterom budovy, tento priestor medzi jednotlivými domami ponúka priehľady na vzdialené horizonty horských lúk. Charakteristika miesta tvoria solitérne domy pozdĺž hlavnej ulice, ktoré sú v tesnom kontakte s okolitou prírodou. Návrh so štyrmi bytovými domami na tieto kvality nadväzuje a rozvíja ich.&nbsp;</p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/Aparthotel%20Sv.%20Vav%C5%99inec%20v%20Peci%20pod%20Sn%C4%9B%C5%BEkou_01.jpg" /></p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/Aparthotel%20Sv.%20Vav%C5%99inec%20v%20Peci%20pod%20Sn%C4%9B%C5%BEkou_03.jpg" /></p>

<p>Ateliér ov-a si za svoju pomerne krátku dobu existencie získal oprávnenú pozornosť laickej aj odbornej verejnosti. Ich návrhy sú charakteristické jasným konceptom a kvalitným spracovaním detailu. Za všetky ich práce možno menovať tie najvýraznejšie: komplex apartmánových hotelov Svätý Vavrinec v Peci pod Sněžkou, nové sídlo firmy LASVIT v Novom Bore alebo prepojovacie mosty budov VŠCHT v Prahe.</p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://singularch.sk/uploads/kcfinder/images/ova_team.jpg" /></p>

<p>V rokoch 2010-2019 sa tým ov-a rozrástol na 8 stálých členov. Kancelária v&nbsp;súčasnosti zároveň nadväzuje na práce na väčšch projektoch a urbanistických celkoch. Len nedávno získali prestížnu&nbsp;<strong>Českú cena za architekturu 2020</strong>.&nbsp;Hlavnú cenu porota udelila Jiřímu Opočenskému a Štefanovi Valouchovi za realizáciu Sídla firmy LASVIT (2019). Autori navrhli pre investora v Novom Bore citlivú rekonštrukciu skupiny tradičných severočeských drevených stavieb z počiatku 19. storočia doplnenú dvoma novými objektmi podobného stavebného objemu, ale v novej reprezentatívnej materialite.&nbsp;Taktiež získlali&nbsp;ocenenie&nbsp;<strong>Architekt roku 2020</strong>.</p>
```

Lets say this is repetaing a few times and I would like to wrap the block to div and image to div.

The expected result is:

```
<div><p><a href="https://www.ov-a.cz/cs/">Ateliér ov-a (Opočenský Valouch architekti)</a>&nbsp;si za svoju pomerne krátku dobu existencie získal oprávnenú pozornosť laickej a odbornej verejnosti. Ich návrhy sú charakteristické jasným konceptom a kvalitným spracovaním detailov. Zo všetkých ich prác môžeme vymenovať tie najvýraznejšie: komplex apartmánových hotelov Svatý Vavřinec v Peci pod Sněžkou, nové sídlo firmy Lasvit v Novém Boru alebo prepojovací mosty budov VŠCHT v Prahe.<br />&nbsp;<br /></p></div>

<div><p><img alt="" src="image" /></p></div>
```

Comment: Please share some sample data and expected output. Without it the question is too broad.

Comment: Please provide two or three sample strings that you get from db covering different cases.